# RODBC connection after "upgrade" to Office 365 ProPlus

Tags: rodbc, error-correction

My computer just got 'upgraded' to Office 365 ProPlus. I rely on RODBC connection for a lot of my work, and after the upgrade it throws the error :

> 1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :   [RODBC] ERROR: Could not
>   SQLDriverConnect 
>   2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection
>   failed" error.

It's the same .accdb file, R version, and code I've been using successfully for months now, so must be some driver/setting issue that cropped up after the update, but I understand too little about ODBC to figure it out. The Access is 32 bit, and so is the R session (I'm using 3.1.0 at the moment). Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Office 2013 doesn't include Access drivers that were included in Office 2010 (isn't upgrading supposed to make something better??). Download the file here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Everything works now.

Comment: I was trying to connect to an ACCESS database that was created using Access 2010 after that I upgraded to Office 365 and Win 10. I had to install this driver to make my R script work.